# Encrypt file with pgp in reactjs web app it's possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gpgpu, pgp

I would like to know if it is possible to create a web app in reactjs to send files, but with the pgp technology?

---

I wanted to look everywhere at our dear friend google but it was never done.

---

I know that with php there is a possibility with the gpgpu function, but I can't find anything for reactJS or VueJS, whatever.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.